# 403 Forbidden: "An expected CSRF token cannot be found"

Tags: csrf, spring-boot-admin

I setup a springboot admin and client accoding to https://codecentric.github.io/spring-boot-admin/2.5.6/#securing-spring-boot-admin.
The admin server is ok,but when I run springboot client , there is a error for CSRS.
How can I resolve the issue.

> 2023-01-30 13:58:08.387  WARN 24920 --- [gistrationTask1]
> d.c.b.a.c.r.ApplicationRegistrator       : Failed to register
> application as Application(name=client,
> managementUrl=http://192.168.111.1:9222/actuator,
> healthUrl=http://192.168.111.1:9222/actuator/health,
> serviceUrl=http://192.168.111.1:9222/) at spring-boot-admin
> ([http://localhost:9111/instances]): 403 Forbidden: "An expected CSRF
> token cannot be found". Further attempts are logged on DEBUG level

springboot client includes

config file:

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityPermitAllConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().permitAll()
                .and().csrf().disable();
    }
}
```

yml file:

```
server:
  port: 9222

spring:
  application:
    name: client
  boot:
    admin:
      client: # spring-boot-admin 客户端配置
        url: http://localhost:9111 #服务端连接地址
        username: admin # 服务端账号
        password: admin # 服务端密码
        instance:
          prefer-ip: true # 使用ip注册

# 服务端点详细监控信息
management:
  # health:  # 检测服务状态是通过http://localhost:9111/actuator/health接口，可去掉不用检测项
  #  mail: # 健康检测时，不要检测邮件
  #   enabled: false
  trace:
    http:
      enabled: true
  endpoints:
    web:
      exposure:
        include: "*"
  endpoint:
    health:
      show-details: always
    logfile: # 日志（想在线看日志才配）
      external-file: ./logs/client-info.log # 日志所在路径
```

pom.xml

```
 <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!--Spring Boot Admin Server监控服务端-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>de.codecentric</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-admin-starter-client</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Comment: .csrf().disable() ???

Answer (score 1):

I got it.
My admin server's pom dependency use javax.servlet instead of spring-boot-starter-web